# timesplices in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have converted the following code from cpp to Objective C

### xyz.h

```
#define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassName,ClassID)                 \
+(ClassName*)FromMsg:(RS232Msg*)pMsg                            \
{                                                               \
ClassName* ivar = [[ClassName alloc]init];                      \
return [ pMsg];                                                 \
}                                                               \
+(RS232Msg*)NewMsg                                              \
{                                                               \
return new ClassName;                                           \
}                                                               \
enum {ID = ClassID};
```

xyz.m

```
@implementation RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions

+ (id)getID
{
    DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions,RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);
    return ID;
}

@end
```

getting errors when using **NewMsg** , **ID** , **FromMsg** from other files.I have included all the header files.

EDITED:

RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions.h

```
#define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassName, ClassID)   \
enum {ID = ClassID};                               \
@interface ClassName: NSObject {}                  \
+(ClassName*)FromMsg:(RS232Msg*)pMsg;              \
+(RS232Msg*)NewMsg;                                \
@end;

#define DEFINE_RS232_NEWMSG_IMPLEMENTATION(ClassName, ClassID) \
+(ClassName*)FromMsg:(RS232Msg*)pMsg                           \
{                                                              \
ClassName* ivar = [[ClassName alloc]init];                     \
return [ivar pMsg];                                            \
}                                                              \
+(RS232Msg*)NewMsg                                             \
{                                                              \
return [[ClassName alloc]init];                                \
}                                                              \
+ (id)getID                                                    \
{                                                              \
return ID;                                                     \
}                                                              \

@interface RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions : RS232Msg{
@public
DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions,RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);
}
@end
```

RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions.m

```
@implementation RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        DEFINE_RS232_NEWMSG_IMPLEMENTATION(RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions,RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

FromMsg undeclared and NewMsg undeclared error occurs.

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'interface'

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '+' token

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'end'

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'interface'

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '+' token

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'end'

error: 'NewMsg' undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be attempting to declare FromMsg and NewMsg as class methods within the class method getID. Objective-C is like C in this respect: you can't declare functions (or methods) within functions (or methods). Furthermore, if you don't declare ID until you're in the source file then it won't be visible to anyone else as the C conventions are followed in terms of compiling each file separately and in isolation, then linking them all together at the end.

It seems likely you're coming from a Java background, so these practices will probably feel a little primitive. Sadly Objective-C deviates quite a lot from the don't-repeat-yourself principle.

If the point of the #define is to create something like a template, I'd suggest you probably want either two levels of header file (one to define the template, one to use it with an appropriate class name and numeric ID) or to use a more conventional class/subclass relationship.

E.g.

xyzTemplate.h

```
#define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassName, ClassID)   \
enum {ID = ClassID};                               \
                                                   \
@interface ClassName: NSObject {}                  \
+(ClassName*)FromMsg:(RS232Msg*)pMsg;              \
+(RS232Msg*)NewMsg;                                \
@end;

#define DEFINE_RS232_NEWMSG_IMPLEMENTATION(ClassName, ClassID) \
@implementation ClassName                                      \
                                                               \
+(ClassName*)FromMsg:(RS232Msg*)pMsg                           \
{                                                              \
    ClassName* ivar = [[ClassName alloc] init];                \
    return [ivar pMsg];                                        \
}                                                              \
                                                               \
+ (RS232Msg*)NewMsg                                            \
{                                                              \
    return [[ClassName alloc] init];                           \
}                                                              \
                                                               \
+ (id)getID                                                    \
{                                                              \
    return ID;                                                 \
}                                                              \
                                                               \
@end
```

xyz.h

```
DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions,RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);
```

xyz.m

```
DEFINE_RS232_NEWMSG_IMPLEMENTATION(RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions,RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);
```

Though the FromMsg declaration looks a bit dodgy (ivar will leak and the pMsg argument isn't used; you'll invoke a method called pMsg regardless of the value of the argument with the same name), and you probably don't want to use the 'id' type in getID since 'id' is an untyped object in Objective-C, so a pointer in implementation terms.  You probably want to return an integer type.

Comment: @Tommy:The explanation you gave here is very useful for me.But i'm with errors still.

Comment: You're still trying to define methods within the body of a method. You can't do that in Objective-C.

Comment: @Tommy:I cant declare this in the @interface of xyz.h as this declaration contains the declaration of a class DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RS232MsgGetEventDescriptions,RM_GET_EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS);

Comment: @Tommy:So i have declare the declaration and definition of the macro inside the @implementation of the class.

Comment: Declarations that you want to be visible to other source files go in the header file, implementations go in the implementation file. I omitted the @implementation/@end from my suggested macro in error, have updated the code.

Comment: @Tommy:I could not make these declaration and definitions inside my @interface or @implementation as it will again include another class within it and defines the method within it.I can declare on outside the @interface and @implementation.Also i'm invoking using the same classname.My problem is I have 10 such classes with same function definition.so th emacro definition and later found that its not good option to choose.

Comment: If the functions are essentially the same, have you considered just using inheritance? You could provide a couple of class methods in each specific class to return ClassName and ClassID, then call those from the methods in the generic class to provide the correct results. I think the simple fact of the matter is that Objective-C doesn't really do templates, and the C preprocessor isn't as much help as you'd like.